# Data Validation in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to Validateion `group_id` and `user_id`. Don't give the same values

Answer (score 2):

If I am not wrong you are using `attach` to insert data into your pivot table. If that is the case then instead of that you can use `sync`